# Page.query.filter(Page.url.contains(url)) function definition?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

While reading someone's code in Python/Flask, I came across the line:

```
results = Page.query.filter(Page.url.contains(url))
```

I've searched it but can't get a satisfying answer. What do the functions query.filter and url.contains do exactly and what values they return under different conditions like if there are no matches or multiple matches or table doesn't exist. Is page the name of the table or just the name of the class?

Edit: Function in which the line is used

```
@pages.route('/<url>/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def url_view(url):
    from app import get_locale
    page = DataGetter.get_page_by_url('/' + url, get_locale())
    return render_template('gentelella/guest/page.html', page=page)

def get_page_by_url(url, selected_language=False):
        if selected_language:
            results = Page.query.filter_by(language=selected_language).filter(Page.url.contains(url))
        else:
            results = Page.query.filter(Page.url.contains(url))
        if results:
            return results.first()
        return results
```

Comment: Where did you come across this code?  Can you give us more context?

Comment: I'm working on the open source project of an event management system. The code is a part of the function which checks if url exists or not and returns the 404 error page accordingly.

Comment: OK, so if it is open source, then it is not a secret.  Which open source project?  Which file?  Which function? etc... Thanks.

Comment: i think this `Page` is a class and those `url` are just part of that class as a function they are not a reserved function of your database driver or programming language. try to find that `Page` and you can see there how those defined functions work

Comment: I searched for it by couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a bit more research on your own, but to get you started this looks like a [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/queries/) project which is a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensions/) around the SQLAlchemy library. The documentation you need to read is mostly in SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy.

`Page` appears to be a ORM mapping of a database table. The `filter`/`filter_by` [methods](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators) encapsulates the SQL `SELECT` functionality. The `contains` [method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.contains) encapsulates the SQL `LIKE %<OTHER>%` functionality.